# Forced Resources release

Tags: anylogic

I have two parallel streams: the first drives the second by generating an agent belonging to population 2 via a split. The copy agent shares an identification code with the original agent.
In this way I would like that the moment the original agent leaves stream 1, immediately the copy is removed from flow 2.
What I would like to do is force the removal of the copy agent from population 2 (manually remove_pop2()), forcing it to release all the resources taken up to that point.
There is the possibility to do this with a "On_remove" function or it is necessary for the agent to switch to a block of seize.
Attached image of the two streams.
Thank you!
[image: 2 streams details]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send it to a separate flow chart before destroying it. In it, add a `Release` block that releases all seized resources. After that, kill the agent in a `Sink`.

Drag in these blocks: `Enter`, `Release`, `Sink`.

Where ever you kill the agent now, don't. Instead, make it go to to the `Enter` block using something like `enter.take(agent);`.